# Can we export CMS content from a Salesforce CMS workspace?

Tags: lightning-community

I want to migrate CMS content from one org to another dev org.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately at the moment there is [no support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_managed_content_overview.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) for exporting or migrating content. You will have to do it manually. Currently there are no APIs available to create content programmatically.

> NOTE Salesforce CMS only supports Full Copy sandboxes for CMS content and collections. You can't migrate CMS content to a production org. We recommend that you use the CMS app in your production org to create content that you plan to use beyond testing.